# How did the novel "Blindsight", by Peter Watts, end?

Tags: firefall, blindsight

*[Blindsight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindsight_(Watts_novel))* features a group of transhumans on a first contact with an alien species (Rorschach).

In the end, it was mentioned Rorschach were constructing a magnetic cannon from the magnetosphere, did they succeed to destroy Theseus before it crashed into Big Ben?  Are the Rorschachs at the Big Ben completed eradicated? Why does the author conclude that Rorschach will not retaliate from this attack out of game theory?

And why does Theseus/the captain decide to smash into Big Ben instead of escaping?

At the very end of the novel, it mentions the broadcast from human/mission control slowly becomes more "regular", composed of telemetry and occasional desperate signals from the humans. Is it assumed that the vampires were taking control or did something worse has happened?

Comment: Reach *Echopraxia*.

Comment: I expect with the words "The End" or possibly "The End?"